# Saving XML file in AS3 is possible

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var xml:XML = <myXml>
                    <item prop="1" />
                    <item prop="2" />
                </myXml>;
```

I need to save as xml file in local harddisk(project directory).

Is it possible to save in as3 itself?

Comment: Your question wasn't very clear, but the answer was just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I threw this together, and sure enough you can save to .XML using the following as a minimalist example.

```
package com.hodgedev.xmlcreator
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.net.FileReference;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Brian Hodge (brian@hodgedev.com)
 */
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    private var _xml:XML;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        //Calling the save method requires user interaction and Flash Player 10
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, _onMouseDown);

        _xml= <xml>
              <test>data</test>
              </xml>;
    }
    private function _onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        ba.writeUTFBytes(_xml);
        //ba.

        var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
        fr.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, _onRefSelect);
        fr.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, _onRefCancel);

        fr.save(ba, "filename.xml");
    }
    private function _onRefSelect(e:Event):void
    {
        trace('select');
    }
    private function _onRefCancel(e:Event):void
    {
        trace('cancel');
    }
}
```

}

There are some things to note.

- You require Flash Player 10 to use the save method of the `FileReference` class.
- In order to do anything that INVOKES a prompt, Flash requires user interaction like keyboard or mouse input.

In the above I listen for `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` on the stage to serve as the USER INTERACTION which is required to invoke the save prompt.

I setup a basic XML structure within the code (this will typically come from and external source and will work fine both ways.

A `ByteArray` is created and the XML is written to the `ByteArray`.

The save method of the `FileReference` class requires a `ByteArray` and default save name be passed as the two parameters.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I know this post is old, but this is exactly the answer I needed except, how do write the xml using a for loop? E.g. I have a 2D array containing data of textures. I want to create a collision xml map based on the textures xml map.

Like, how do you do:
`var xml:XML = <data> /*for loop*/ <data>`?

Comment: use the for loop to build the actual xml, then send her off!
var s:String;
//Ommit the following, if you wish, flash does not use it, but if the file is shared between front and backend, you may wish to have that tag.

Comment: s = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">";


s.appendText("<data>");

//Feel free to loop how you wish e.g. for(var i:int; i < someValue; i++);  I will use for each
for each(var someObj in SomeOtherObj)
{
    s.appendText("<collision id=" + someObj.id + " />");
}

s.appendText("</data>");

This is obviously generic, but should get you going.
var xml:XML = s;

Comment: Is there any way to save XML without dialog box ?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to store it locally (on the client PC) , you can use a local shared object. Refer to this [tutorial](http://www.tutorio.com/tutorial/flash-cookies-local-shared-objects-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, your question isn't very clear.

Are you asking if you can save a file to the hard drive from within a compile SWF written in AS3?

Or are you asking if you can include a raw XML file in your AS3 project without needing to write it out as a variable?

If you meant the former, no -- not without Adobe AIR.  You can save data locally as a SharedObject, but not as an arbitrary file in the file system.

If the latter, then yes -- you must embed the file just as you would embed another resource (such as an image or a sound).  However, it looks like there might be a bug in Flash that makes this non-trivial to figure out how to do.

[This link might be of help to you.](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=6208.0)

```
[Embed(source='../../../../assets/levels/test.xml', mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
public static const Level_Test:Class;
```

And then to parse the XML:

```
var ba:ByteArray = (new Levels.Level_Test()) as ByteArray;
var s:String = ba.readUTFBytes( ba.length );
xml = new XML( s );
```

Apologies if neither of those questions are what you were actually asking.

Cheers!